# How to find the Exit Pages in GA4 API?

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

With the old Google Analytics (UA), it was possible to retrieve the exit pages;
I cannot find a way to get the same data from GA4 API.

Does anyone knows how to do it?

Thanks,
Ludovic

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask] edit your question include enough details to help us understand your issue. include any code or error messages you are getting.    For example GA4 does not have **pages** it has events, so show us in the documentation for GA4 what exactly it is you would like to see extracted.

Comment: I too am very confused by exit_page not existing in GA4 - I get the hit based nature of GA4 but companies still want to know the last page a customer was on before they left the site - there should be an obvious way of finding this without having to come up with clever regex etc (like you have to for pagepath)

Comment: Do you guys have any information regarding retrieving the exit pages? @odevney

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue, I think bounceRate is the most similar in this concrete case. Or has to be the "substitutive" metric until there is a GA4 special metric for this use.